# Setup Etherpad on a IIS7 machine with Port 80

Tags: iis7, web-services, configuration

I downloaded [Etherpad for Windows](http://etherpad.org/)
On IIS7 Server I've created the directory "`etherpad`" and now I want to access from external. But while IIS Service is working on Port 80 the etherpad service is working on Port 9001.

Can someone explain me please how to create public access? 
Is there a configuration of IIS needed and redirecting the data?
Or do I need to change the settings in Etherpad service?

Comment: Don't use IIS :(

Comment: That is no option. Additional I am sure it works great, I just need to know how.

Comment: According to the [Readme on GitHub](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/blob/master/README.md), 9001 is the default port.  I'd need to see the start.bat file

Comment: My question is not to change the port. Or what would you change it to? Port 80 is not possible in case it is HTTP port. The port can be changed on config.js without problems. But this would not help.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the site in IIS Manager. Click on Edit Bindings.  Click add binding and choose port 80.   If port 80 is being used by another site (in IIS) then you will need to add a specific hostname (domainname) so IIS knows to route port 80 traffic for that domain.  Also have to setup DNS to point to your IIS server or create a phony hosts file entry for local testing.